# Django REST framework: how to respond with useful error messages with get_queryset()

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework, http-status-codes

I have a django model which I want to display via Django Rest framework. I am getting all objects in the model to be displayed via the `get_queryset()`. However, I also have a couple of `query_params` which will filter out certain objects. This is my main code which is working fine:

```
class PlanView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint which allows prices to be viewed or edited
    """

    serializer_class = PlanSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    # override method
    def get_queryset(self):
        //get all objects in Plan model
        queryset = Plan.objects.all()

        // possible query parameters to be read from url
        size = self.request.query_params.get("size", None)
        price = self.request.query_params.get("price", None)

        if size is not None:
            if size == "large":
                queryset = queryset.filter(Large=True)
            elif size == "small":
                queryset = queryset.filter(Large=False)

        if price is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(price=price)

        return queryset
```

with this `urlpattern`:

```
path(r'API/plans', views.PlanView.as_view(), name='prices'),
```

The only problem is that when I purposefully write the below URL in a browser,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/API/plans?size=sm
```

which has a bad/misspelled `query_param` value, the get_query() code will just ignore it and display the objects as if there are no filters.

I tried to put an else statement such as:

```
    if size is not None:
            if size == "large":
                queryset = queryset.filter(Large=True)
            elif size == "small":
                queryset = queryset.filter(Large=False)
            else:
                return Response({"Error":"bad request"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but with this, I get an error message saying:

```
ContentNotRenderedError at /API/plans
The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.
```

How can I display useful error responses/jsons if a user puts in a wrong parameter value in the API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ValidationError`

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
# ...
        raise ValidationError(detail="size must be either 'large' or 'small'")
```

DRF catches these exceptions and displays them neatly. It returns a JSON of the form

```
{
    "detail": "size must be either 'large' or 'small'"
}
```

Comment: If you really need to raise it manually, you should raise a `ValidationError`.  `APIException` is a 500 (server error, not validation error/400).  The `code` parameter isn't the HTTP status, its a string and only accesible in the `ErrorDetail` objects before the value is serialized to the client.

Comment: @AndrewBacker You are right, I changed my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to handle this: `1)` manual validation or `2)` using the `django-filters` package.

**1) Manually raise a ValidationError (simplest)**

```
if size not in ['small', 'large']:
    raise ValidationError(f"Invalid size {size}.  Please use small/large")
else:
    # filter normally.  remember to consider the '' value
```

**2) Use [django-filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/install.html) (best)**

Filters help you separate the filtering and sorting logic from your viewset, and remove the need to manually check/parse/validate the incoming data.  In the case of a `ChoiceFilter` ([docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#typedchoicefilter)) it will also validate the input and raise an error for you.

```
from django_filters import TypedChoiceFilter
from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet, DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.fields import CharField
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


class MyFilter(FilterSet):
    # this will return a 400/validation error if not a or b
    # but it will ignore blank.
    size = TypedChoiceFilter(
        field_name='Large', # your column name was 'Large'
        choices=[('small', 'Small'), ('large', 'Large')],
        convert=lambda value: value == 'large'  # true if value is Large
    )

class MyView(ListAPIView):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_class = MyFilter
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return TheModel.objects.all()
```

Looking at your schema, if this question is accurate, you could also use the method documented in the filters package or a `BooleanFilter` if you change the name to `is_large`, e.g. `is_large=True`.