# How to raise errors in ListApiView DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class GetFollowers(ListAPIView):

    """
    Returns the users who follw user,along with weather the visiter — the one who sent api request — 
    follows them or they follow him/her
    """

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = None

    def get_queryset(self,*args,**kwargs):
        user = self.request.data.get('user',None)
        
        if user is None:
            pass

        followers_obj, created = Follow.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        
        all_followers =  followers_obj.followers.all()
```

Now , when a user sends a request , along with the one's username , in query_params, whose he/ she wants to get followes, how do I return an error if the sender doesn't follow the one whom he wants to get followers.

Comment: you can check if you have received anything in all_followers or not and you use `try` and `except` or you can `raise exception` whenever you wanted.

Comment: this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842907/django-rest-framework-how-to-respond-with-useful-error-messages-with-get-querys. might be useful.

Comment: I want to send a response to sender which will be {'permition denied':'Can't see user's followers'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can raise `ValidationError`

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class GetFollowers(ListAPIView):

    """
    Returns the users who follw user,along with weather the visiter — the one who sent api request — 
    follows them or they follow him/her
    """

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = None

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some code
        if not_followed_condition:  # I hope you know what you need to check here
            raise ValidationError(
                {'permission denied': "Can't see user's followers"}
            )
        # some other code
        return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks, tough I was able to figure it earlier, I kept the question to help others.